# Incorrect proof of Hahn Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fake-proofs

What is wrong with the following trivial proof of the Hahn Banach Theorem?

**Hahn Banach Theorem:** Let $V$ is a real normed vector space and $U$ a subspace.  Then if $\phi : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional bounded by $C>0$, then there exists an extension of $\phi$, $\phi ': V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, also linear and bounded by $C$.

**"Proof"**: Since $V/U$ has a basis (by the axiom of choice), it seems we can lift it to get a complimentary subspace $W \subset V$ such that $V= W \oplus U$ (as vector spaces).  Then just define $\phi'(w+u)=\phi (u)$.

But this can't be right….

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How do You even know that $\phi'$ is continuous? You need to ensure that there exists $C_1$ such that $||u||\leq C_1||w+u||$ for any $w\in W, u\in U$ and to get Hahn-Banach You need $C_1=1$. Your proof works in unitary spaces since You can always take for $W$ an orthogonal complement of $U$.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I thought for sure the hole was in thinking that $U$ had a complimentary subspace.  Thank you.